# Creating columns in a dataframe using data from another dataframe with conditions without using for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have two dataframes, df_1 and df_2

df_1 has 30k+ rows and looks like this

```
Col_1_1    Col_1_2    CA_CB
a          c          CA
a          c          CB
a          d          CA
b          c          CA
b          d          CB
b          d          CB
b          c          CA
```

I'd like to create two columns in df_1 using data coming from df_2 if column CA_CB = "CB"

df_2 has 1k row and looks like this (Col_2_1 has unique values)

```
Col_2_1    Col_2_2
a          data on a
b          data on b
c          data on c
d          data on d
```

My output should look like this:

```
Col_1_1    Col_1_2    CA_CB    Col_target_1    Col_target_2
a          c          CA       "X"             "X"
a          c          CB       data on a       data on c
a          d          CA       "X"             "X"
b          c          CA       "X"             "X"
b          d          CB       data on b       data on d
b          d          CB       data on b       data on d
b          c          CA       "X"             "X"
```

The way I'm doing it currently is creating Col_target_1 and Col_target_2 with

```
df_1["Col_target_1"] = "X"
df_2["Col_target_2"] = "X"

for i in range(len(df_1)):
    if df_1["CA_CB"][i] == "CB":
        for j in range(len(df_2)):
            if df_1["Col_1_1"][i] == df_2["Col_2_1"][j]:
                df_1["Col_target_1"][i] = df_2["Col_2_2"][j]
            if df_1["Col_1_2"][i] == df_2["Col_2_1"][j]:
                df_1["Col_target_2"][i] = df_2["Col_2_2"][j]
```

This is doing the job I want it to. But it is taking 20+ minutes to do so, and I was wondering if it could be run faster using another method.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a series mapping from `df_2`:

```
s = df_2.set_index('Col_2_1')['Col_2_2']
```

Then map conditionally to `df_1` using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df_1['CA_CB'] == 'CB'

df_1['Col_target_1'] = np.where(mask, df_1['Col_1_1'].map(s), 'X')
df_1['Col_target_2'] = np.where(mask, df_1['Col_1_2'].map(s), 'X')
```

`mask` returns a Boolean series, which `np.where` uses to decide element-wise whether to select the second or third arguments.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you very much !
Takes less than 0.5 seconds !